# CakePHP 3 custom validation: how to compare new value with old value during edit?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp-3.0

I have a case where I want to allow user to only increase value during edition. To do so I'd have to compare new value passed in request with old value from entity stored in DB.

Custom validation function receives two arguments: `$check`, which is a value to be validated and array `$context` which contains other values from submitted form.

What is the best way to validate edition in the manner I need in CakePHP 3? Is it even possible with validation rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [**Application Rules**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#creating-a-rules-checker)

You have to create a new new rule in your Table object

suppose that the field that you want to check is `priority`

So in your rule you check the value of `priority` (that has just been changed) against the original value stored in `$entity->getOriginal('priority')`

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{

    // This rule is applied for update operations only
    $rules->addUpdate(function ($entity, $options) {
        if($entity->priority >= $entity->getOriginal('priority'))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }, 
    'CheckPriority', // The name of the rule
    [
        'errorField' => 'priority', // the field you want 
                                    // to append the error message
        'message' => 'You have to set a higher Priority' // the error message
    ]);

    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is corroct answer.